# how to copy text from one text-field to other text-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have a disable date-text-field with a calendar j query on it.
the problem is i want to copy date-text-field text to another text-field On Change.

Comment: Add the query that generates the report and some sample data

Comment: What if `ID's` are repeating. Still you need only 5 records

Comment: then i will use distinct. hope so it works

Comment: as i 9 unique ID never repeat..

Comment: Then you got the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM <TABLENAME>
ORDER BY Id DESC
```